# WKWebView doesn't present the HTML string in Mac OSX

Tags: html, macos, view, wkwebview, xcode9

In new xCode 9.0:
I tried simply to load a HTML string inside webView (WKWebView) but I got a blank screen!
The strange thing is the same code is works in my other computer!

Is this a bug?

Here is the code

```
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "my HTML file name", ofType: "html")
    let htmlStr = try! NSString.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlStr as String, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to allow 'Outgoing Connections (Client)' in the project's capabilities. Make sure these are added to the entitlements file as well.

I know, it does not make any sense if you don't make any outgoing connections and just pure HTML, but this made it work for me.